# Implementing PlateJS in a React App: Compilation Error with '@udecode/plate-core' and 'nanoid/non-secure'

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm attempting to integrate PlateJS into my React application for rich text editing features. I use `create-react-app` and `@craco/craco` for setting up and configuring my app. However, when trying to include PlateJS's `@udecode/plate-core` package into my project, I'm encountering the following compilation error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@udecode/plate-core/dist/index.mjs
Attempted import error: 'nanoid' is not exported from 'nanoid/non-secure' (imported as 'nanoid2').
```

I suspect the issue is related to the `nanoid` package, but I've verified that it's correctly installed by checking its presence in my `package.json`.

Steps I've taken so far:

- I've deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, then reinstalled the dependencies with `npm install`.
- I've tried different versions of `nanoid` (latest and previous versions).
- Ensured that I'm using the latest versions of PlateJS and its dependencies.

I'm using `craco` with a configuration file in my project and haven't made any specific configurations related to PlateJS.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion on how I could resolve this issue? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!